# "Mix" operator does not wait for upstream processes to finish

Tags: nextflow

I have several upstream processes, say A, B and C, doing similar tasks.
Downstream of that, I have one process X that needs to treat all outputs of the A, B and C in the same way.

I tried to use the "mix" operator to create a single channel from the output files of A, B and C like so :

```
process A {
    output:
    file outA
}
process B {
    output:
    file outB
}
process C {
    output:
    file outC
}

inX = outA.mix(outB,outC)

process X {
    input:
    file inX

    "myscript.sh"
 }
```

Process A often finishes before B and C, and somehow, process X does not wait for process B and C to finish, and only take the outputs of A as input.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet works nicely:

```
process A {
    output:
    file outA
    """
    touch outA
    """
}

process B {
    output:
    file outB
    """
    touch outB
    """

}

process C {
    output:
    file outC
    """
    touch outC
    """
}

inX = outA.mix(outB,outC)

process X {
    input:
    file inX

    "echo myscript.sh"
}
```

If you continue to experience the same problem feel free to open an [issue](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues) including a reproducible test case.